# How many approved posts have been rejected?

Tags: support

Is there a way to tell how many of my approved edits have ended up being accepted, or visa-versa?

I know there's an immediate feedback if the post was already approved/rejected. But say I'm the first to vote and I reject, but the next three approve. Is there a way to tell how accurately I'm marking these edits compared to other people?

Comment: You would be able to write a DE query for this; http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just because 3 others accepted an edit suggestion, does not mean it was right. Certainly not while the robo-reviewer problem is still around.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've created a query on the Data Explorer [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/206296/suggested-edits-voting-compared-to-final-result)

```sql
select
  count(*) as ApprovedByUserAndApprovedAsFinalResult
from
  SuggestedEdits se
  inner join SuggestedEditVotes sev on sev.SuggestedEditId = se.Id
where
  sev.UserId = ##UserId##
  and se.ApprovalDate is not null
  and sev.VoteTypeId = 2 -- UpMod

select
  count(*) as RejectedByUserAndRejectedAsFinalResult
from
  SuggestedEdits se
  inner join SuggestedEditVotes sev on sev.SuggestedEditId = se.Id
where
  sev.UserId = ##UserId##
  and se.RejectionDate is not null
  and sev.VoteTypeId = 3 -- DownMod

select
  count(*) as ApprovedByUserAndRejectedAsFinalResult
from
  SuggestedEdits se
  inner join SuggestedEditVotes sev on sev.SuggestedEditId = se.Id
where
  sev.UserId = ##UserId##
  and se.RejectionDate is not null
  and sev.VoteTypeId = 2 -- UpMod

select
  count(*) as RejectedByUserAndApprovedAsFinalResult
from
  SuggestedEdits se
  inner join SuggestedEditVotes sev on sev.SuggestedEditId = se.Id
where
  sev.UserId = ##UserId##
  and se.ApprovalDate is not null
  and sev.VoteTypeId = 3 -- DownMod
```

Comment: Thank you. Also did very similar here: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/206289/my-approved-edit-votes-that-were-approved

Comment: Huh. Neat. Apparently I'm a reject-happy jerk. And I'm okay with that.

Comment: @BillyMailman: Infinitely more likely is that others are robo approvers...

Comment: @PlasmaHH That's not really much of a problem over on Arqade, actually. Data.SE scripts work on any site.

Comment: @BillyMailman: ehm, huh? I am not really sure how arqade comes into the game and that that have to do with DE working for every site. I am merely stating that its likely that a big "I have rejected, other have approved" number wil be because of robo approvers.

Comment: I was indicating that I only really review suggested edits over on arqade. Couldn't review 'em if I wanted to on SO.